# Configure TFS builds to use a different app.config for tests than the local machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, build

We have a build definition for our project that's set to continuous integration and which runs all the unit tests on every check in. It was all running fine until recently, when it began to reject a handful of tests that worked on developer machines.

A moment's examination revealed that this was because the tests were dependent on an external file template for which the path was specified in the app.config file. It was a network drive which developer machines had access to, but which didn't exist on the build server.

The project is a WPF application. Ideally I'm going to try and refactor the code to see if I can bypass that external dependency. But if I can't, or just to satisfy my curiosity, is there a way of editing the build itself to use or deploy a different config file?

Answer (score 2):

You have a much bigger problem: Your code and your tests are dependent on some random, external, uncontrolled file. That file should be something that's source controlled and deployed along with your application.

You also have an external dependency in your tests: It has to read that file from the file system. You may want to break that dependency using standard inversion of control techniques so that tests can run in true isolation, without any need for a file to be present in the file system.

Comment: Thanks. I realised the truth of this and started refactoring as soon as I'd posted the question. The offending code is now sealed behind an interface. Still curious if there's a way of changing the config, as I can imagine other scenarios where it might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

SlowCheetah should work for this use case.

[Nuget.org - SlowCheetah](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/)